# NullReferenceException Error when trying to iterate a IEnumerator

Tags: linq, ienumerable, nullreferenceexception, object-reference, ienumerator

I have a datatable and want to select some records with LinQ in this format:

```
  var result2 = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                              where row.Field<string>("Media").Equals(MediaTp, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                                    && (String.Compare(row.Field<string>("StrDate"), dtStart.Year.ToString() +
                                                                                    (dtStart.Month < 10 ? '0' + dtStart.Month.ToString() : dtStart.Month.ToString()) +
                                                                                    (dtStart.Day < 10 ? '0' + dtStart.Day.ToString() : dtStart.Day.ToString())) >= 0
                                    && String.Compare(row.Field<string>("StrDate"), dtEnd.Year.ToString() +
                                                                                   (dtEnd.Month < 10 ? '0' + dtEnd.Month.ToString() : dtEnd.Month.ToString()) +
                                                                                   (dtEnd.Day < 10 ? '0' + dtEnd.Day.ToString() : dtEnd.Day.ToString())) <= 0)
                              group row by new { Year = row.Field<int>("Year"), Month = row.Field<int>("Month"), Day = row.Field<int>("Day") } into grp
                              orderby grp.Key.Year, grp.Key.Month, grp.Key.Day
                              select new
                              {
                                  CurrentDate = grp.Key.Year + "/" + grp.Key.Month + "/" + grp.Key.Day,
                                  DayOffset = (new DateTime(grp.Key.Year, grp.Key.Month, grp.Key.Day)).Subtract(dtStart).Days,
                                  Count = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Count"))
                              };
```

and in this code, I try to iterate it with the following code:

```
 foreach (var row in result2)
 {
   //... row.DayOffset.ToString() + ....
 }
```

this issue occurred :
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I think it happens when there's no record with above criteria. 
I tried to change it to enumerator like this , and use MoveNext() to check the data is on that or not:

```
    result2.GetEnumerator();
 if (enumerator2.MoveNext()) {//--}
```

but still the same error.

whats the problem?

Comment: @SarahN ... `if(result2!=null) foreach(......){...}`

Comment: @Thirisangu A linq query will never return `null`. The problem is inside the query.

Comment: @Sloth A LINQ query never return `null` !!! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess in one or more rows `Media` is `null`.

You then call `Equals` on `null`, which results in a `NullReferenceException`.

You could add a null check:

```
var result2 = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
              where row.Field<string>("Media") != null
                 && row.Field<string>("Media").Equals(MediaTp, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                 ...
```

or use a surrogate value like:

```
var result2 = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
              let media = row.Field<string>("Media") ?? String.Empty
              where media.Equals(MediaTp, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
              ...
```

*(note that the last approach is slightly different)*